# Module connection error (flask statistics)

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to use a module 'flask-statistics' in my Flask project

Project structure
app/

- __init__.py
- models.py
- one_page_main_logic.py
- admin.py

__init__.py contains create_app() with BluePrints (admin, one_page_main_logic)

```
create_app():
    ...

    database = models.db
    database.init_app(app)

    statistics = Statistics(app, database, models.RequestStat)
    
    ...
    return app
```

from models.py I returned 'db = SQLAlchemy()'

ERROR:
from flask_sqlalchemy import Model
ImportError: cannot import name 'Model' from 'flask_sqlalchemy'

I tried:

- reinstall flask-sqlalchemy
- change program logic and move init db functions to __init__.py

but I want to maintain the logic that I originally followed